# Why can't I get the correct textbox value on Razor page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is simple webpage with textbox and alert box to show its value on a razor view page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Enter your name")   
                @Html.TextBox("txtName")
            </div>  
            <input type="button" id="btnPost" value="Load Data using Post" />

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    //$("#txtName").keyup(function () {
                    //    alert(this.value);
                    //});
                    var originvalue = $("#txtName").val();

                    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
                        alert(originvalue);
                    });
                });
                });
            </script>
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

I have taken the textbox value and assigned it to a var `originvalue`. Now I want to show this value in an alert box. Is this some kind of bug? I can't figure out what is missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you only set `originvalue` when the page loads and the `input` has no value in it. If you want to retrieve the value the user typed, set that variable *inside* the click handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnPost").click(function () {
        var originvalue = $("#txtName").val();
        console.log(originvalue);
    });
});
```

Also note that your original JS code has one set of closing braces/brackets too many, and you should also use `console.log()` to debug over `alert()` because the former does not coerce data types.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your

```
 $("#btnPost").click(function () {
                        alert(originvalue);
                    });
```

with

```
$("#btnPost").click(function () {
                        alert($("#txtName").val());
                    });
```